# For hard links why does the file have to be on the same linux file systems?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I am wondering why for system hard links the file linked has to be on the same file system. Where for soft links the file the linked does not necessarily have be on the same file system.

Comment: There is a good answer on StackExchange UNIX and Linux: [Why are hard links only valid within the same filesystem?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290525/why-are-hard-links-only-valid-within-the-same-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Please note: file is contained on file system as set of i-node metadata and blocks of data.

Hard links are different names of the same file. Directory contains file names and link to their i-nodes address (place of file on filesystem). So hard-link (file name) should be on the same fs as i-node, and respectively as another hard-link (file name). Also i-nodes are not unique across all file systems on the same directory tree.

Symlinks are linked to filenames on directories tree. All filesystems share single directory tree and sym-link (soft link) can point anywhere, as paths are unique in system.